# Are there other solutions of $x^{x^3-x}=2^{x^2+x}$ than $x=-1 $ and $x=2$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, lambert-w

I have tried to solve that equation $x^{x^3-x}=2^{x^2+x}$ in $\mathbb{R}$  , I have got only two integers solutions which they are : $x=-1$, $x=2$ , are there others ?

**Note:** if we try to study this : $\frac{x^3-x}{x^2+x}=\frac{\log x}{\log 2}$, I think there is a numerical solution in the range $( 0,1)$ using value intermediate theorem, it is to show that there is a solution here, but i can't determine it

Comment: Another obvious solution is $x=0$ because $0^0=1=2^0$

Comment: Wolfram finds a solution around $x≈0.346323$.

Comment: Thanks so much, i didn't montioned that because i have consedred x=0 as indeterminate case

Comment: I don't think we should consider 0 a solution as $0^0=1$ is debatable.

Comment: $0^0$ is an *indeterminate form* (mostly because $(x,y)\mapsto x^y$ is not continuous there) but not an *undefined expression*. $0^0$ is the number of maps from the empty set to the empty set.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm not sure that I would say that $0^0=1$ _in $\mathbb{R}$_ - which is explicitly what the title of the question asks about. This certainly comes down to semantics, but I wouldn't fault someone for saying that $x=0$ is not a solution.

Comment: $2$ is not a solution and $-1$ does not belong to the domain of $x^{x^3-x}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Write your equation in the form
$$\ln(x)-\frac{x^2+x}{x^3-1}\ln(2)=0$$, define

$$f(x)=\ln(x)-\frac{x^2+x}{x^3-1}\ln(2)$$ and use calculus.

Comment: So you want to tell me that you have a closed form for the $0.346323\dots$ solution?

Comment: This can i not tell you, sorry, but you can construct the image of the function and you will get the Information, how many solution the equation has.

Comment: @Dr.Sonnhard Graubner , But you didn't add any thing to my above note ,I want to add me somthing otherwise than i have wrote above

Comment: You will never find all solutions of your equation, but with my hint, you can prove how many solutions the equation has.

Answer (score 0):

I think the domain should be restricted to positive real numbers. I mean, the expressions make sense for some negative numbers, but not so many of them. (It is problematic to raise a negative number to a non-integer exponent.)

So let $x$ be positive. Then after taking the logarithm we obtain: $(x^2+x)\log 2= \log x\cdot (x^3-x)$. Simplyfying by $x$ and $x+1$ yields $\log 2= \log x\cdot (x-1)$, or equivalently $\log 2- \log x\cdot (x-1) =0$. Clearly $x=2$ is a solution. The function $f(x)= \log 2- \log x\cdot (x-1)$ on the left is strictly monotone increasing on $]0,1[$ and decreasing on $]1,\infty[$ (pay attention to the signs). As $f(1)>0$, there can be two roots, one on each interval. There is one on $]1,\infty[$, namely $x=2$. There is also one on $]0,1[$, as $f$ changes signs there. For example $f(1/4)< 0$.